# Remove border from top-left cell of a table in TAB

Tags: tables

I am using TAB environment and I need to remove the border from the top left cell of my table, I used the solution recommended for `tabular` environment but it didn't work.

PS: I would prefer not to change into `tabular` and stick with `TAB`.

```
% \usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\begin{table}[htbp] 
\begin{TAB}(c,1cm,1cm)[10pt]{|c|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|c|}
& Mathematics (M) & Physics (P)   & Language (L)\\
Student A & 16    & 16    & B  \\ 
Student B & 18    & 18    & C \\
Student C & 16    & 15    & B \\
\end{TAB}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple of solution, with `TAB` environment and with an ordinary `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\myrule}{\rule[-.4cm]{0pt}{1.05cm}}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{With TAB and some hacking, but the solution is not perfect}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
\begin{TAB}(c,3.4cm,1.4cm)[10pt]{|c}{|c|c|c|}
Student A \\ 
Student B \\
Student C \\
\end{TAB}&
\begin{TAB}(c,3.4cm,1.4cm)[10pt]{|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|c|}
Mathematics (M) & Physics (P)   & Language (L)\\
 16    & 16    & B  \\ 
 18    & 18    & C \\
 16    & 15    & B \\
\end{TAB}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Much better with a \texttt{tabular}}
\begin{tabular}{|*4{M{3cm}|}}
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\myrule}& Mathematics (M) & Physics (P)   & Language (L)\\
\hline
\myrule Student A & 16    & 16    & B  \\ 
\hline
\myrule Student B & 18    & 18    & C \\
\hline
\myrule Student C & 16    & 15    & B \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason why i used the TAB environment is because i wanted the the table to be well organized , but since that could be achieved with tabular , i will be using the tabular environment, thank you very much .

Comment: @lily You're welcome! Unfortunately, `TAB` has some limits...

Comment: Yes, i figured that out . It gives clean organized tables , but only if the structure is as  simple as possible.